# Notice message Array to string conversion in _menu_router_build() while installing drupal openpublish in MAMP OS X Lion

Tags: php, apache, drupal, osx-lion, mamp

While installing the Drupal Open Publish 7, there is notice message, repeating more than 100 times saying

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in _menu_router_build() (line 3603 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/njpg.org.np/includes/menu.inc).
```

I don't want to hide this notice message but fix this. How Can I do this?

I have installed Drupal Open Publish 7 on MAMP 3 with PHP 5.4.10 and Apache 2 / OS X 10.7. Is it a MAMP specific error or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the line 3603 in includes/menu.inc as suggested by Amal Murali. Previously the line had

```
array_multisort($sort, SORT_NUMERIC, $menu, SORT_STRING);
```

I changed it to

```
array_multisort($sort, SORT_NUMERIC, $menu, SORT_ASC);
```

This solved the problem

---

There seems problem with parameters in `array_multisort()` function. The documentation gives the syntax of `array_multisort()` as

```
array_multisort(array1,sorting order,sorting type,array2,sorting order...)
```

Where, `array1` and `array2` are array to be sorted, `sorting order` is `SORT_ASC` or `SORT_DESC` and `sorting type` is type of variable to use to be sorted. Sorting order and sorting type is optional.

Comment: @ Prabhu: The line number is the only thing that's different. You could have edited the other answer and marked it as complete, since there's not much difference between these two :)

Answer (score 3):

Change line 3603 in `includes/menu.inc` to:

```
array_multisort($sort, SORT_NUMERIC, $menu, SORT_ASC);
```

That should fix the issue.

Comment: May be it is line 3603?

Comment: @Prabhu: yeah whatever line matching this statement. Change it.